# Project specific settings for Indent size?

Tags: pycharm

I have a mix of "2 spaces" and "4 spaces" projects, is there a way to set indentation setting on per-project basis?

Right now under preferences it seems like a global settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select `Project` instead of `Default` in **Scheme** dropdown:

[image]